# Extract all data from a dynamic HTML table

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, html-table

Here is my issue :

For a Excel writing app, I'm extracting data from an HTML table.
I have a website which contains the table, I can go through it and extract data.

BUT

as the table shows only 20 rows, I can only extract the first 20 rows and not the whole table (which row numbers are pretty random).

Note that the HTML table reset his td/ID as row0 to row19 each time you scroll down (probably usual but I'm not an HTML pro :D )

I have no idea how I could go through the whole table with no duplicates of row data.

If anyone has an idea, you're welcome !

Edit 1 :

here is the HTML (I've filtered it to have only col1 as I need for my extract)

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/yfb429Lo/13/`
```

Indeed, there is a scroll tab on the right of the table as on the screenshot here :

[Table_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76A0K.png)

When I scroll 2 times downward through the table, the HTML update himself to become like this :

==> row2 become row0, row3 become row1, ...

I have something like 100 tables to extract and I can't know the table length by advance.

Thanks all,

Arnaud

Comment: Add some details of HTML and code

Comment: A link to the page would be very helpful. When you say scroll down, do you mean scroll down the page or are you referring to switching to another page/panel with more table data? e.g. when you scroll down, does the original table data remain or is it replaced with the new data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing, here is the answer :

```
 try:
        last_row = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr/*[contains(@id, '--TilesTable-rows-row19-col1')]")
        last_row_old = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr/*[contains(@id, '--TilesTable-rows-row19-col1')]").text
        last_row.click()
        last_row.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
        time.sleep(2)
        last_row_new = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr/*[contains(@id, '--TilesTable-rows-row19-col1')]").text

        while (last_row_new == last_row_old) is False:
            table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, '--TilesTable-table')]/tbody")
            td_list = table.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr/*[contains(@id, '-col1')]")
            for td in td_list:
                tile_title = td.text
                sh_tile = wb["Tuiles"]
                sh_tile.append([catalog, tile_title])
            last_row = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr/*[contains(@id, '--TilesTable-rows-row19-col1')]")
            last_row_old = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr/*[contains(@id, '--TilesTable-rows-row19-col1')]").text
            last_row.click()
            last_row.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            last_row_new = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr/*[contains(@id, '--TilesTable-rows-row19-col1')]").text
    except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract rows using xpath instead of td/IDs since they are not constant.

Click the next page button then Extract the rows again until next page button click gives you NotFoundException (depends if the button is not visible on the last page). If you provide the HTML or website link you will get a better answer.